# textfield.getText used in multiple update queries returns null in the second query

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have problem with textField.getText() that I used in several queries, so in the second query that textField.getText() returns null value tha cnnot be saved in database

and this is my code in actionPerformed of my Save_Button

```
if (evt.getSource() == btn_save_project) {
            try{
                Statement state = DBConnection.getInstance().createStatement();

                String query1 = "insert into projet values(pro_sequence.nextval,"
                + " '"+txt_projet.getText()+"', (select id_mission from mission "
                + "where nom_mission = '"+txt_mission.getText()+"'))";

                String query2 = "insert into date_etat values('"+txt_date.getText()+"')";

                String query3 = "insert into etat_de_projet values((select "
                + "pro_sequence.currval from dual), (select id_etat from etat where "
                + "nom_etat = '"+cmb_etat.getSelectedItem().toString()+"', '"+txt_date.getText()+"'";

                System.out.println(query1+"\n"+query2+"\n"+query3);

                state.executeUpdate(query1);
                state.executeUpdate(query2);
                state.executeUpdate(query3);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        }
```

and when I excute it displayed the following in the console

```
insert into projet values(pro_sequence.nextval, 'random', (select id_mission from mission where nom_mission = 'Maintenance'))
insert into date_etat values('')
insert into etat_de_projet values((select pro_sequence.currval from dual), (select id_etat from etat where nom_etat = 'Debut', ''

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: impossible d'insérer NULL dans ("MYPROJECT"."DATE_ETAT"."ETAT_DATE")
```

the last line tells that it's impossible to insert null value in date_etat

any help please?

Comment: Well, txt_date is empty. We cn't tell more than that with the code you posted. This code is not safe at all (just think what would happen if you had a quote in one of the text fields). Use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. And don't mix database access code with GUI code. Pout the database access code ina  separate class.

Comment: thank you @JB Nizet for your advice I totally agree with you to seperate database  code from gui code, but sometimes we need text that we have just insert in pervious command but with little modification. even if textFields display the text but they are empty, so how to use our previous insert into actual insert without  retyping in all textFields?

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Comment: hi @JB Nizet my problem is suppose I create a table  create table person(id numeric(6) primary key, name varchar2(20), city varchar2(20)) and I will insert data from my gui into database so this is the code <code> insert into person values(seq.nextval, 'textField1.getText()', 'textField2.getText()') </code> suppose that the first person and the second have the same city so we aren't going to change city_name in the next insert in our gui but the problem is that after the first insert textFields become empty

Comment: textfields don't become empty by themselves. And inserting a row doesn't clear text fields. If you don't want your text field to be cleared after an insert, then don't clear them. That has nothing to do with separation of GUI and database code anyway.

Comment: Hi @JB Nizet TextFields become empty after each insert, please see the example I gave above when it displays insert into date_etat values('')

Comment: No they don't. What makes you think it's the insert that clears the text field? It's not. It's already empty when this code is executed. Think about it: why would executing an insert in a database clear a text field? Do you really think the database driver cares about your text field, knows it exists, can reach it, and clears it? It doesn't make any sense. Your code has a bug.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that txt_date is empty. I can't say why, since all I know about your code is what you posted.